# Prove a condition from properties of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix of rank $n-1$.  Suppose also that $Au=0$, where $u=(1,1,...,1)^T$.  Show that $Ax=y$ has a solution if and only if $\sum_{j=1}^ny_j=0$.

Symmetric matrix means that $A^T =A$.  The equation $Au=0$ means that the sum of the components of a row or column vector is equal to $0$.

Since every component of the $y$ vector is equal to $0$, $Ax=0$?  I don't see how this can be the only solution to $Ax=y$.

So, I see now that the sum of the components of $y=0$.  This means that any combination of the columns is equal to $0$.  I feel like the proof of this is connected to the fact that the rank is $n-1$, but I do not see how.

Comment: Not every component of $y$ is $0$ the sum of the components is!

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot more sense.  I still don't see why $Ax=y$ if true IFF the sum of y's components = $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=Ax$,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^ny_j=u^ty=u^T(Ax)=(u^TA)x=(A^Tu)^Tx=(Au)^Tx=0
$$

Reversly, if $\sum_{j=1}^ny_j=0$, then $\;u^Ty=0$, meaning it's orthogonal to $u$.

Since $\ker(A)=Span\{u\}$, and $A$ is symmetric with rank $\;n-1$, you can find a base of the image of $A$, with all the vectors orthogonal to $u$. That means that the image of $A$ is exactly the orthogonal space $u^{\perp}$, and so $y$ belongs to the image

Comment: Thanks.  Once I saw that $\sum_{j=1}^ny_j=u^ty$ it made sense.  That was the connection that I was missing.